# No notification when someone comment my answer

Tags: support, comments, notifications

Today I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19310534/in-contentpage-the-jquery-is-not-firing). Later, I failed to get any notifications for comments that were posted for my answer.

[image]

My inbox is filled with comments, but no red notification appeared. Why is that?

**Note:** I'm sure that I didn't have the inbox open in another tab.

Comment: When you load your inbox, what does it look like? Are you sure you didn't just dismiss it without noticing?

Comment: @animuson I'm sure that I didn't see any notification (red icons) while I check my inbox

Comment: You most likely have the inbox open somewhere, maybe in a forgotten tab maybe even different computer. When you have it open in one place, no red numbers will appear.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd seems weird, now I'm getting count notification for other answers.  But I'm sure that I didn't opened the inbox in other tab.  let me close this question, since the problem persisted only for me.

Comment: Seems to be off-topic This happened only for me, so I think this is not a big deal now I am getting notifications for the other answers.

Comment: This happens to me all the time.  New comments to my answers without @myname don't generate notification, though seems like only sometimes, hard for me to test easily.